# Can I deref futures/promises in clojure.core.async/go?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, clojure, core.async

I'm trying to find a way to harmlessly observe many `future`s. By that, I mean without blocking N threads to wait for N `future`s.

I see that `core.async` library is build in a way it doesn't block thread with blocking operations, but rather park it and reuse the thread. Is it the case with deref, or it works only with `<!` and `alts!`?

Comment: your title sounds like you are asking how to do this in a go block, and your question sounds like you are asking how to do this with futures and not in a go block. which are you looking for?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I'm looking for a way that doesn't end in *thread* being blocked by waiting for deref.

Comment: Do you have to use clojure's futures? I'd avoid them at all cost in real world usage. Use other means such as `ztellman/manifold` library.

Comment: @ClojureMostly futures can be stopped with `future-cancel`, which differentiate them from other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

the `future-done?` function can be used to poll an array of futures to see which ones are ready to be looked at:

```
main> (future-done? (future 42))
true
main> (future-done? (future (Thread/sleep 1000) 42))
false
```

you can then create a function that polls all the futures (in a vector perhaps) for one to work on, then goes and does the work. this way instead of blocking a thread on *each* future, you block a thread on *any* future and decide how many such workers you want (one at a time is a common choice)

If you want it to be more efficient, or more expressive, than this you would be creating a state machine to track which futures to check and work on which would put you on the path to recreate your own version `clojure.core.async/alts!` and might do better to use core.async all the way.

Comment: So the best approach may be using separate thread that constantly checks all futures you have whether are they done or not? While it works, it just doesn't look as clean solution somehow.

Comment: added an answer to this into the question